# Getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object" on SQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables in my database:

Statements

[image]

and Tags

[image]

I'm trying to execute this query

`SELECT s.id, s.name, s.preview, s.approved FROM Statements s JOIN Tags t ON s.id = t.probID WHERE s.approved = TRUE AND t.tag IN ("Geometry") GROUP BY s.id, s.name, HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 1`,

but getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\file.php on line 46", where 46th line is `while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){`

Is something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using MySQLi, correct me if I am wrong.

In the span of time I used it, whenever this kind of problem was presented to me, I had a problem with the query which I was not able to identify before the execution. Given that my query had failed, no `SQLStatement` object (or whatever its name is) was created. Therefore, no `fetch_*` method could be called on that!

I believe your problem is a very simple one: you have a trailing comma before your `HAVING` clause which is messing your query up. I reproduced your SQL structure and query on my PC, and everything worked correctly.

```
SELECT 
  s.id, s.name, s.preview, s.approved 
FROM 
  Statements s JOIN Tags t ON s.id = t.probID 
WHERE 
  s.approved = TRUE AND t.tag IN ('Geometry') 
GROUP BY s.id, s.name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 1
```

Try this one out.
Just a note: whenever I have to deal with a `true or false` in SQL and I am storing it as a `*INT UNSIGNED`, I feel like using `1` as `true` and `0` as `false` never creates any problem, while using `TRUE` or `FALSE` sometimes does! This was not the case, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use `var_dump($result);` don't use it. Instead of that, put the result in the $result variable. `$result = $stmt->get_result();`

Comment: I don't use `var_dump`, I'm using `$res = $conn->query($select);`